# About the limitation of the literal object syntax

Tags: javascript

I know that the limitation of the literal object syntax is that the names has to be literal.

By the way I need to accomplish the following task, which way do you recommend me?

I have an object obj1 which I want traverse and then pass to another function which accept only literal object like parameter.

I wrote just the basic example to get the basic idea of what I am asking.

The problem is on the last loop, see the inline comments.

```
obj1 = {k1 : 1} // simple literal object

fn = function (json) {
    // this function can accept just  literal object 
    console.log("result: ", json); // {key : true}, but I want {k1 : true}
}

for (key in obj1) {
    obj = [];
    fn ({
        key : true // I want the key to be k1 and not key
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the good responses, they are all valid. So I reward the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this...

```
var obj = {};
obj[key] = true;
fn(obj);
```

That is about as elegant as you will get. Please do not use `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to use a variable as a key.

```
function fn(obj) {
    console.log("result: ", obj);
}

for (var key in obj1) {
    var temp = {};
    temp[key] = true;
    fn (temp);
};
```

Also note the use of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) (so you don't create globally-scope variables) and the different style function declaration.

Comment: Declaring a `var` inside of a loop (where it does not get its own scope) is a little confusing, though.

Comment: Just trying to keep things clear for the OP. You think it would be less confusing to n00bs to declare `var temp;` outside of the loop and then just set it in the loop?

Comment: Unfortunately, the way variable scoping in Javascript works is always going to confuse newcomers, probably even more so if they have done programming in other languages before. Yes, declaring the var on top of the loop is less confusing since it is closer to how the variable actually works. That is an unnatural way to write it, but forcing yourself to do it that way is forcing yourself to think about this. Or use CoffeeScript ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 // this function can accept just  literal object
```

No. The function does not care how the parameter object was constructed.

You can do

```
 obj = {};
 key = "k1";
 obj[key] = true;
 fn(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

> another function which accept only literal object like parameter.

There's no such thing. Outside of the moment it is created, there is no difference between an object created using a literal and one created some other way.

```
for (key in obj1) {
    obj = [];
    var foo = {};
    foo[key] = true;
    fn (foo);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try this?

```
for (key in obj1) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = true;
  fn (obj);
};
```